# Best way to get an enum by numeric id

Tags: java, enums

I need to create an enum with about 300 values and have the ability to get its value by id (int). I currently have this:

```
public enum Country {
    DE(1), US(2), UK(3);

    private int id;
    private static Map<Integer, Country> idToCountry = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (Country c : Country.values()) {
            idToCountry.put(c.id, c);
        }
    }

    Country(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static Country getById(int id) {
        return idToCountry.get(id);
    }
}
```

That enum is going to be used a lot, so I'm wondering if this is the best possible solution performance-wise.

I've read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html over and over again, but couldn't find the part that describes at what time the

```
static {

}
```

block is called, and if it is guaranted that this will be called only once. So - is it?

Comment: Static initializer blocks are called once [when the class is initialized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7). It's not guaranteed to be called once, but it will be unless you're doing something exotic with class loaders.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! @AndyTurner Would you recommend another way of initalization, or should I go with this?

Comment: This looks fine. The only thing I'd change is to make `id` `final`. (And `idToCountry` `final` too). An alternative would be to put them in an array (assuming your IDs are non-negative and reasonably contiguous) - this would allow you to avoid autoboxing the `id`.

Comment: Ok, I will. Thanks a lot! @AndyTurner

Comment: Note that you should (probably) use `GB` to represent the United Kingdom, rather than `UK`. `GB` is the abbreviation defined in [ISO-3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) (although `UK` is a reserved abbreviation, defined to mean the same as `GB`).

Comment: @AndyTurner I only used GB in the MVCE, the original data uses the ISO spec you linked too :-)

Comment: @Michael Why don't you use the `Enum`'s `ordinal()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static initializer blocks are called once [when the class is initialized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7). It's not guaranteed to be called once, but it will be unless you're doing something exotic with class loaders.

So, your approach is *probably* fine from a performance perspective. The only changes I'd propose would be to make your fields `final`.

---

An alternative way to represent the mapping could be to store elements in an array (or a list):

```
Country[] countries = new Countries[maxId + 1];
for (Country country : Country.values()) {
  countries[country.id] = country;
}
```

You could then look them up by element index:

```
System.out.println(countries[1]);  // DE.
```

This avoids the performance penalty of having to box the `id` in order to call `idToCountry.get(Integer)`.

This of course requires you to have non-negative IDs (and ideally the IDs would be reasonably contiguous, to avoid having to store large runs of `null` between countries).

Comment: Yeah, I will go with the alternative, great tip!

Comment: @Michael. Note that you would really need to do a lot of lookups for HashMap.get() (the hashcode computation for Integer is trivial, as it just returns the integer value) to be your performance issue here. While the hashmap is a lot cleaner with less chance for error (such as requiring a range check on the requested ID).

Comment: @Michael I agree with Thirler. Try Hashmaps first, only use the array if you find there is still a performance issue.

Comment: @Thirler it's not the hashcode computation that's the performance issue, it's the implicit call to `Integer.valueOf(id)` - OP says there are 300 IDs, so there are necessarily some not-necessarily-cached values (as in, the max ID must be >128, so you can't rely upon it being cached).

Comment: That's interesting. Actually, (I must admit that I didn't see that before), there are some countries assigned to multiple ids (didn't think someone would really do that). So I'm back on the HashMap, assigning the values in a loop to the Map

Comment: @AndyTurner Fair enough, but still hardly any application has performance problems with Autoboxing ( = creating objects) these days. Either way, as always with performance: measure to find your bottleneck, improve, measure again.

Answer (score 3):

In case if the first country id is `0` and ids are incremented by `1`, you may use the next approach:

1. Cache enum values in array. `Enum.values()` returns elements in the same order as they declared in enum. But it should be cached, as it creates new array every time it is invoked.
2. Get values from cached array by id, which will be array index.

Please, see the code below:

```
enum Country {
    A, B, C, D, E;
    private static final Country[] values = Country.values();

    public static Country getById(int id) {
        return values[id];
    }
}
```

UPDATE: To get Country's id, `ordinal()` method should be used. And to make getting id code clearer, the next method can be added to the enum:

```
public int getId() {
    return ordinal();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you don't need to have a static block to create the map. You can just add your code to constructor where each component adds itself to your map. Enum is ALWAYS a sigleton so your constructor is guaranteed to be called only once (per a enum value) Also you don't need to even have ID as Enum has method [public final int ordinal()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) that returns its zero-based sequential number in the enum. In your case ordinals would be 0 for DE, 1 forUS and 2 UK.

Here is an example:

```
public enum Country {
DE, US, UK;

private static Map<Integer, Country> idToCountry = new HashMap<>();

    Country() {
       idToCountry.put(this.ordinal(), this);
    }

    public static Country getById(int id) {
        return idToCountry.get(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: For this code I get compiler error
`Cannot refer to static enum field Country.idToCountry within an initializer` on line `idCountry.put(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too. Simple as it shows.

```
enum Country {
  DE(1), US(2), UK(3);

  public int id;

  Country(int id) {
  this.id = id;
}

 public static Country getCountry(int id) {
    Country[] c = new Country[Country.values().length];
    c = Country.values();
    return c[id];
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot.